# Accessing elements of a list in another class

Tags: c#, list, class

Lets say I have something like the following.

```
namespace BurgerMachine
{
public class BaseList{

    private static readonly List<Bases> bList = new List<Bases>() //might need to take off readonly
    {
        new Bases(){ BaseID=1, BaseName="Bun"},
        new Bases(){ BaseID=2, BaseName="SeededBun"}
    };
    public static List<Bases> GetList()
    {
        return bList;
    }
}
    public class Bases
    {
        public int BaseID { get; set; }
        public string BaseName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now I would like to access the elements of the above list from another class, is this doable with my current setup or do I need to be returning more?

I have seen a few examples of people creating a List and then adding to from another class but not trying to access elements that already exist. If such an example does exist please point me in the right direction.

First time using Lists in this fashion so I'm not quite sure what I am doing. Any help would be great. If more information is needed please ask.

Comment: Your `GetList` method is `static` (not sure if you want that), so I'm not sure where the issue lies. Is there any issue in calling `BaseList.GetList()`?

Comment: You've only shown us half the code; whet do you want the code that *consumes* the list to look like? Is it doing a `foreach` over the list, or inserting new items, or what?

Comment: Like John said, just use `var list = BaseList.GetList();` and then you can access your elements in the List like in any other readonly List. And to "answer" your comment "might need to take off readonly", only if you want to add/ remove elements

Comment: @MindSwipe the `readonly` modifier only affects the `bList` field, disallowing a reassignment after field initialization/constructor. It's possible to add elements to the `List<Bases>` returned by `GetList()` regardless of the `readonly` modifier. If `List<Bases>` was a `ReadOnlyCollection<Bases>` it would not be possible to add or remove elements.

Comment: @Johnbot woops, my fault, was still half asleep when I wrote that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are few implementations best way to return list.

**With static class**

```cs
public class BaseListProvider
{
    public static readonly Bases Bun = new Bases() { BaseID = 1, BaseName = "Bun" };
    public static readonly Bases SeededBun = new Bases() { BaseID = 2, BaseName = "SeededBun" };

    public static IEnumerable<Bases> GetList()
    {
        return new[]
        {
            Bun,
            SeededBun
        };
    }
}

public class Bases
{
    public int BaseID { get; set; }
    public string BaseName { get; set; }
}
```

**With interface which can be helpful if you are using dependency injection**

```cs
public class BaseListProvider : IBaseListProvider
{
    public static readonly Bases Bun = new Bases() { BaseID = 1, BaseName = "Bun" };
    public static readonly Bases SeededBun = new Bases() { BaseID = 2, BaseName = "SeededBun" };

    public IEnumerable<Bases> GetList()
    {
        return new[]
        {
            Bun,
            SeededBun
        };
    }
}

public interface IBaseListProvider
{
    IEnumerable<Bases> GetList();
}

public class Bases
{
    public int BaseID { get; set; }
    public string BaseName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: are you not over complicating what could have been simple?

Comment: Totally agreeing with Rahul, also you're rewriting OP's code to the point where it doesn't do the same anymore, you're creating a new Array (not even a List how OP asked)  every time you call the Method

Answer (score 2):

Well you could just make the list a `public` member like below and access it from wherever you want

```
public List<Bases> bList = new List<Bases>()
{
    new Bases(){ BaseID=1, BaseName="Bun"},
    new Bases(){ BaseID=2, BaseName="SeededBun"}
};
```

You can access now saying

```
var blist = new BaseList().bList;
```

With your current setup (as already commented) why can't you just call the static method saying `BaseList.GetList()`